# Can ArcGIS Explorer open an NTF file?

Tags: arcgis-explorer

I have numerous .NTF files I need to open and take a look at but not sure which software package I need to view the images.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/900/en/index.html with my bolding:

> ArcGIS Explorer supports the display of many raster formats,
>   including: Imagine image (.img), bitmap (.bmp), JPEG (.jpg, .jpeg),
>   Portable Network Graphics (.png), Graphics Interchange Format (.gif),
>   Tagged Image File Format (.tif, .tiff), ARC/INFO and Space Imaging BIL
>   (.bil), ARC/INFO and Space Imaging BIP (.bip), ARC/INFO and Space
>   Imaging BSQ (.bsq), DTED Level 0-2 (.dted), ERDAS 7.5 LAN (.lan),
>   ERDAS 7.5 GIS (.gis), JP2 (.jp2), MrSID (.sid), RAW (.raw), **NTIF
>   (.ntf)**, USGS ASCII DEM (.dem), X11 Pixmap (.xpm), PC Raster (.map),
>   PCI Geomatics Database File (.pix), JPC (.jpc), J2C (.j2c), J2K
>   (.j2k), HDF (.hdf), BSB (.kap).